# Can not select daylight saving time in AnyTime datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, anytime

AnyTime datepicker: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

I am unable to select for example, if I'm in in this timezone:
Sun, 29 Mar, 02:00  CET → CEST  +1 hour (DST start) UTC+2h
I am unable to select 2015 29 march 02:00

I would like to be able to select this time, I will handle ambiguities in the back-end!

On another note, I am able to select the date when CET -> CEST resulting in an ambiguety. But I'd like to handle these ambigiueties in the back end (with NodaTime), is there an option I can set so that I can select any date/time?

Edit: added picture for clarity!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but let me try to help. The default anytimetz.js contained a bug that prevented CET (and BST) from appearing in the timezone-selection popup.  I just corrected the bug.  Please download the new anytimetz.5.0.6.js and let me know if it solves your problem.  If it does not, then please let me know more details. For a faster response, use the contact link on the website. Thanks!

Comment: I've added a picture for clarity! I want to be able to select any date, currently I can't select '02' shown in the image.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see.  This is a tough one. The problem is, the library uses actual JavaScript Date objects internally to manage the date/time you've selected. So, when you click 02, it tries to call the Date.setHours(2), but then the JavaScript object says, "no, that's not valid in your current timezone" and changes it to the value it wants instead.  I'm working on a replacement library that won't use JS Date objects, but its nowhere near completion.

Comment: I dunno if this will help or not, but it seems that if your system clock is set to a different timezone, you can select the value you want. But I certainly wouldn't expect end users to change their PC date/time settings just to work around the issue.  I'll keep thinking about the problem, but I doubt there is a solution, given the current implementation's heavy dependency on JavaScript Date objects. :(

Comment: Thank you for your help and the awesome datepicker :D ! Small, note: If I set the timezone to Moscow, I still can't select it, But Moscow has no daylight saving, I think this might be a bug.

Comment: Strange, in my own timezone, it works.  There were some timezone changes in Russia last year that caused all kinds of bugs in certain browsers; not sure if it's related.  But it's definitely cause by the JS Date dependency, which is too coupled to undo in the current library.